# Cocoapods gRPC-Core installs failed

Tags: ios, firebase, uikit, cocoapods

I am using Xcode version 13.4.1 to install fireabse,

1. I've tried 2 times to use [Swift Package Manager](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git) which failed & I don't have interest in SPM which has biggest drawback of downloading each time randomly when opening xcode. I don't have internet data for it.
2. I've tried Cocoapods secondly,

   ```
   platform :ios, '13.0'

     target 'App' do
     use_frameworks!

     pod 'FirebaseAuth'
     pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
   end
   ```

**Console output:**

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.24)
Installing FirebaseAppCheckInterop (10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth (10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreExtension (10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal (10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestoreInternal (10.20.0)
Installing FirebaseSharedSwift (10.20.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher (3.3.1)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.12.0)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.3.1)
Installing RecaptchaInterop (100.0.0)
Installing abseil (1.20220623.0)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.49.1)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.49.1)
```

But the pod installing failed after **dowloading nearly 1GB on `gRPC-Core (1.49.1)`** with error

```
[!] Error installing gRPC-Core
[!] /usr/bin/git -C /var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re submodule update --init --recursive

Submodule 'third_party/abseil-cpp' (https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp.git) registered for path 'third_party/abseil-cpp'
Submodule 'third_party/benchmark' (https://github.com/google/benchmark) registered for path 'third_party/benchmark'
Submodule 'third_party/bloaty' (https://github.com/google/bloaty.git) registered for path 'third_party/bloaty'
Submodule 'third_party/boringssl-with-bazel' (https://github.com/google/boringssl.git) registered for path 'third_party/boringssl-with-bazel'
Submodule 'third_party/cares/cares' (https://github.com/c-ares/c-ares.git) registered for path 'third_party/cares/cares'
Submodule 'third_party/envoy-api' (https://github.com/envoyproxy/data-plane-api.git) registered for path 'third_party/envoy-api'
Submodule 'third_party/googleapis' (https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis.git) registered for path 'third_party/googleapis'
Submodule 'third_party/googletest' (https://github.com/google/googletest.git) registered for path 'third_party/googletest'
Submodule 'third_party/libuv' (https://github.com/libuv/libuv.git) registered for path 'third_party/libuv'
Submodule 'third_party/opencensus-proto' (https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-proto.git) registered for path 'third_party/opencensus-proto'
Submodule 'third_party/opentelemetry' (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto.git) registered for path 'third_party/opentelemetry'
Submodule 'third_party/protobuf' (https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git) registered for path 'third_party/protobuf'
Submodule 'third_party/re2' (https://github.com/google/re2.git) registered for path 'third_party/re2'
Submodule 'third_party/xds' (https://github.com/cncf/xds.git) registered for path 'third_party/xds'
Submodule 'third_party/zlib' (https://github.com/madler/zlib) registered for path 'third_party/zlib'
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/abseil-cpp'...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/benchmark'...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/bloaty'...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel'...
error: 2894 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/google/boringssl.git' into submodule path '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel' failed
Failed to clone 'third_party/boringssl-with-bazel'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/cares/cares'...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/envoy-api'...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/googleapis'...
error: 6417 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis.git' into submodule path '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/googleapis' failed
Failed to clone 'third_party/googleapis'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/googletest'...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/libuv'...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/opencensus-proto'...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/opentelemetry'...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/protobuf'...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/re2'...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/xds'...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/zlib'...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel'...
error: 6813 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/google/boringssl.git' into submodule path '/private/var/folders/bd/0lx6myh56h74477qjythpqkr0000gn/T/d20240201-3616-1a418re/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel' failed
Failed to clone 'third_party/boringssl-with-bazel' a second time, aborting
```

I really frustrated for 2 days of trying it. I really don't know how to fix this issue. Can you please help me to fix it?

**Swift:**

```
swift-driver version: 1.45.2 Apple Swift version 5.6.1 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.66 clang-1316.0.20.12)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx12.0
```

**Pod Version: `1.15.0`**

**Command Line tools version:**

```
version: 13.2.0.0.1.1637719136
volume: /
location: /
install-time: 1643314355
groups: com.apple.FindSystemFiles.pkg-group
```

Thanking you!

Answer (score 0):

The logs

```
error: 6813 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

Suggests there is problem when downloading more than 1GB git. I've faced similar error when cloning `webkit.` So this is an issue in the `cocoapods` & `swift package manager` downloads whole repository instead of cloning most recent version ony.

I've got remote computer to install pods to get pods folder. That's the only solution now.